# A repeat reminder not showing after 1 year in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I have added a new repeat reminder in Google Calendar. If you look forward in the calendar that repeat stops after 1 year. Why? The "Ends" is set to "Never".
Starting from July 2017 the reminder is missing from the calendar.

[image: Reminder screenshot]

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't replicate this. I created a reminder to repeat every 1 year, and when I looked at each of the next dates (through 2020) there were all there.

Comment: I think he meant a daily recurring event with no end date, as opposed to an event that occurs once a year. This isn't clear in the question.

Comment: I have added a montly repeat reminder. Ends is set to "never". It shows up to one year in the calendar.

Comment: It seems that Google Calendar is only acting on data for up to a year for you. Perhaps this is a regional restriction. What country are you in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question it sounds like you created a recurring daily event, not a Calendar reminder. Reminders appear on your calendar each day until you mark them as done. You can create them using [these directions](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

While I didn't find it documented anywhere, in my experience daily recurring events will only appear on your calendar for the next year, but this will update every day. In other words if this daily event shows up for June 10th, 2017 but not June 11th, 2017 right now, wait 24 hours and it will then appear for June 11th, 2017. To put it yet another way, you should see daily recurring events for approximately the next 365 days, regardless of the current date.

Comment: I hope so. It's a bit disconcerting to rely on Google to remind me of super important things that *have* to be done, like paying my property taxes, and just "hope" it doesn't stop reminding me after a couple of years!